# Best way to perform a number of HTTP requests to the same IP

Tags: python, multithreading, http, python-requests

I have a class that sets up multiple threads where each thread would perform an HTTP POST request. Out of 15000 requests, I get about 400 failures.

```
Exception in thread Thread-13290:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 110, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='some_ip_here', port=8880): Max retries exceeded with url: {some_api_endpoint} (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8479af71d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 24] Too many open files',))
```

I perform around 50 POST requests concurrently at any point. What is the best way to do 100 consecutive (separated by 10 seconds) 50 concurrent HTTP POST requests?

Comment: You _do_ close the connections after posting your requests, _don't you_?

Comment: Who gives the error "[Errno 24] Too many open files" your code or the server you are connecting ?